# Mix raw queries and ORM operations within the same cftransaction

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, cfquery, stalestateexception

Is it safe to mix raw queries using `cfquery` and ORM operations within the same `cftransaction` tag?

```
<cftransaction>
    <cfquery datasource="test">...</cfquery> <!--- A --->
    <cfset var e = entityLoadByPK('SomeEntity', someId)> <!--- B --->
    <cfset e.setSomeProperty('test')> <!--- C --->
    <cfquery datasource="test">...</cfquery> <!--- D --->
</cftransaction>
```

By having a look at the SQL profiler, it seems that the queries won't get executed sequentially, they appear in the profiler in the following order: A, B, D, C. From what I understand, this could happen because the hibernate session will get flushed only when it reaches the closing `cftransaction`, is that correct?

I have noticed that because of another issue **wich I will ask a in another question**. But basically, I have to disable triggers on a specific table before running the ORM statement or it will result in a `StaleStateException`.

When having the ORM operation between `DISABLE TRIGGER` and `ENABLE TRIGGER` statements within the same `cftransaction`, it did not solve the issue, because `ENABLE TRIGGER` ran **before** the ORM query. However, when using the following, it works:

```
<cfquery datasource="test">
    DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON Test;
</cfquery>

<cftransaction>
    <!--- ORM CODE --->
    <!--- Other cfquery --->
</cftransaction>

<cfquery datasource="test">
    ENABLE TRIGGER ALL ON Test;
</cfquery>
```

I also tried to use `ormFlush()` right after the ORM statements, but it did not worked. Is there a way to mix raw queries and ORM statements within the same `cftransaction` and having the statement to run sequentially? Maybe I am misunderstanding the issue completely, but I am quite puzzled right now.

Comment: I'd look closely with `ormFlush()` again.  I believe that does work and I've used it before with no problem.

Comment: @Henry, I will have to wait until monday to double check. If you have CF installed, could you confirm your statement by inserting 3 rows (without orm, orm, without orm) in a table and check the outcome? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using ORMExecuteQuery.

```
ORMExecuteQuery("update SomeEntity set SomeProperty = 'test' where id = :id",
  {"id"="someId"});`
```

These get executed right away and skip the ORM session.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I haven't took the time to further investigate the issue and check if my assumptions were right however. Do you know how things are handled when mixing raw queries with ORM operations and also why using `ormFlush` woudln't work in my case? I will post additionnal information about the issue soon.